# Line, Plane or Hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra, span

Does span=(2,-1,1,2), (-2,1,-1,-2) represent a line, plane or hyperplane in R4?

We haven't learned matrices yet either

Comment: What distinguishes lines, planes, and hyperplanes? Clearly dimension, but how do we know the dimension of the span of a set of vectors?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, let **x** be one of the two vectors, then the other vector is -**x**. This means they lie on the same line which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}.$

Answer (score 1):

How $(2,-1,1,2)=-(-2,1,-1,-2)$ are dependent, then represent a line in $\mathbb{R}^4$